# Versions of The Demolished Man

Tags: history-of, the-demolished-man

[Alfred Bester](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alfred_Bester)'s novel [*The Demolished Man*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Demolished_Man) was initially published (in *Galaxy* magazine) with such character names as “T8”, [“$$son”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3857/jackson-son-pun-or-topical-reference), “@kins” and “¼maine” (a precursor to SMS-speak). The subsequent book publication greatly toned down the use of such abbreviations. Short of locating old issues of *Galaxy*, is the original version available somewhere?

[ISFDB](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?2122) does not mention any differing versions.
My source for the existence of the original version is [Randall Garrett](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Randall_Garrett)'s review in verse in *Takeoff!*.

Comment: I read the The Demolished Man not long and never found any SMS-Speak names in it. The version must have removed or renamed them.

Comment: There is a very second hand book shop, close to where I'll live, with a vast SF section. I'll check it out.

Comment: @scope_creep: [My edition](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?THDMLSHDMN1999) has “Samuel @kins” midway through chapter i. In the original, Tate (mentioned in the same sentence) was called “T8”.

Comment: The copy I read had the abbreviations.  Sadly I think it was borrowed.

Comment: As with Gilles, my copy has @kins, ¼maine and Wyg&, but not T8 or $$son. It's a Pocket paperback from around 1980.

Comment: $$son was removed by an editor from the book - it relies on slang that was arcahaic even at the time of publication; "Jack" for a US Dollar.

Comment: @Covertwalrus Thanks. Do you have a reference that would make a better answer for http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3857/jackson-son-pun-or-topical-reference ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The book "Galaxy, thirty years of innovative science fiction" states the story was published as "Demolished" in 1952, but I can't find any reprints in anthologies.

However, you can buy DVD collections of Galaxy stories on eBay.

Comment: By now the 1952 *Galaxy* serial is available at the Internet Archive: [Part 1](https://archive.org/details/Galaxy_v03n04_1952-01), [Part 2](https://archive.org/details/Galaxy_v03n05_-_1952_02_-_Galaxy), [Part 3](https://archive.org/details/galaxymagazine-1952-03).

Answer (score 6):

My copy is packed away somewhere, but it has this cover:

[image]

... and it has the SMS-ish abbreviations.  [According to the web page where I found that picture](http://bentspine.blogspot.ca/2010/12/nice-jacket-1-demolished-man.html), it's the 5th printing by Signet.